# FileUpload not supported with primefaces 5.1 or higher

Tags: java, primefaces

I have very strange issue. I use FileUpload via prime face and it works perfectly.
I use primefaces 5.0.
Now I wanted to upgrade to primefaces 6.0, I got error in the following:

```
import org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent;
import org.primefaces.model.UploadedFile;
```

It says: Package org.primefaces.event.FileUploadEvent doesn't exist

I use Maven:

```
<repository>
     <id>prime-repo</id>
     <name>Prime Repo</name>
     <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
</repository>

<dependency>
     <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
     <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
     <version>6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I got the same error if I use version higher than 5 (5.1, 5.2,...)

It is strange but I have no idea why.

Comment: Where do you get your primefaces jar files from? When using the primefaces maven repository, the FileUploadEvent is there. I am using PF 6. Make sure to rebuild your project.

Comment: Are you using eclipse? Try update project. Also check that there is no pom using an older version. Finally try delete or rename your maven repository and do a build install to see if it clears out old dependencies.

Comment: @tak3shi When I tried to rebuild: Could not transfer artifact org.primefaces:primefaces:jar:6.0 from/to prime-repo (http://repository.primefaces.org)

Comment: I get my primefaces jar from: http://repository.primefaces.org

Comment: @farrellmr I am using Netbeans.

Comment: I cant see version 6.0 listed on that repository - http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/primefaces/. Use maven central as PF state the repo.primefaces is for older releases

Comment: Reference - http://www.primefaces.org/downloads

Comment: @farrellmr Sorry I didn't understand you. Which repository should I use?

Comment: Maven Central - http://search.maven.org - its should be a default repo in settings.xml

Comment: I am sorry, still unable to get your point. If it is a repository problem, what is the url for the repository for primefaces 6. I couldn't find one in Maven Central - search.maven.org, or maybe I miss understood you. What is setting.xml?? Should I have xml file called setting?

Comment: Read my answer below - that should fix the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if you got this fixed - but i suspect the problem is that primefaces 6.0 is not in your repository -

```
<repository>
 <id>prime-repo</id>
 <name>Prime Repo</name>
 <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>
</repository>
```

You should remove the above as primefaces recommend it for older versions of PF -

> PrimeFaces 4.0 and newer are available at Maven Central, for older
>   releases and RC releases add the following repository definition to
>   your pom.xml in repositories section.

The maven default will now be the central repository which contains 6.0 -

> Apache Maven retrieves all components from the Central Repository by
>   default. Starting with Maven 3.2.3 the default access is via HTTPS and
>   no further configuration is required.

http://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Corg.primefaces%7Cprimefaces%7C6.0%7Cjar

Ref -

http://www.primefaces.org/downloads

Comment: Thank you so much... the problem is fixed